# Fail to get permission to get current longitude and latitude

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, location, latitude-longitude, android-permissions

I am trying to make my program able to get the user's current longitude and latitude and then place a marker to it. I have used various method in the Internet but none of them seemed to work. From what I have observed I suspect the reason the trouble is that the program fails to get the permission, despite I have already set it in the manifest

Here is the code, I currently only use setMyLocationEnabled to demonstrate the problem

```
    package com.example.user.googlemaptest2;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double longitudeDefaultLocation;
    private double latitudeDefaultLocation;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 11;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 12;

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitudeDefaultLocation = location.getLongitude();
            latitudeDefaultLocation = location.getLatitude();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                    MapsActivity.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION );

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  },
                    MapsActivity.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION );

        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    public void onSearch(View view)
    {

        EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;
        if (location !=null || location.equals("")) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);


            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng( address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }

    }


    public void changeType (View view)
    {
        if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
        {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        }

        else
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }


    public void onZoom(View view)
    {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomInButton);
        {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomOutButton)
        {

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());

        }


    }
```

This is the content of my Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.googlemaptest2">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="My Key is Here" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your targetSDK 21 or 22?

Comment: I choose API 15 Android 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich) as the minimum SDK

Comment: SDK version 24, from the build.gradle it seems

Comment: In which device are you testing the code ? Because from android 6 onwards permission is required at run time.

Comment: I use the emulator, it says Marshmallow Android 6.0 x86

Comment: Please check the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Minimum SDK is not relevant for the question. If you set targetSDK below 24, the system will provide backwards-compatibility shims, and XML (static) permissions may be enough.